# Warning: array_merge in admin side

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I was created custom module. & use below code for get language file. So, it was working fine in OpenCart 1.5.6.4.

(admin\controller\module\custom.php)

```
$language = $this->load->language('module/custom');
$this->data = array_merge($this->data, $language);
```

**but, it is not working in Opencart 2.0.**

Get below error in admin side module in OpenCart 2.0

```
Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array
```

How can I fix it?

Would appreciate the help.

Comment: Please post `$this->data` since the warning says it's not an array

Comment: if, i have use `$data = array_merge($this->data, $language);` though, create same error.

Comment: @HarnishDesign of course it would be the same error. It tells you that the first argument of function (`$this->data`) is not an array. Check the content of that variable.

Comment: Thanks. I have remove `$this->data` from our code & it is working fine. Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have remove `$this->data` from our code & it is working fine.

Correct code.

```
$data = array_merge($language);
```

Comment: It can also work with $this->data , array_merge expects first parameter to be an array ,you have to declare this variable as an array before using it.

Comment: `array_merge($language)` - what do you think is the result of this call? Didn't you want to call `$data = array_merge($data, $language);`???